# cycle efficiency for (otto -diesel -dual) at constant Pr & Temp

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, energy-efficiency

It's written that at constant pressure & temperature for Otto & Diesel cycles
the efficiency of diesel is more than efficiency of Otto.
Efficiency = Work / Heat added = 1- (Heat rejected / Heat added )

from fig :
-(4->1)  Heat rejected is same
-(2'->3) Heat added for diesel is greater than (2->3) )heat added for Otto

so for diesel the term (Heat rejected / Heat added ) is less

**so efficiency of diesel is more.**

What make it not clear for me is that
work ( Cv(T4-T3) ) (3->4)  is same for both & heat added for diesel is more than that of Otto.
So if we use  eff= Work/(heat added)
**Eff of otto will be more since less heat will be added and same work is done**,
What makes it wrong?

[image: P-V For same pressure and temperature]

source : http://slideplayer.com/slide/10748942/  slide 30

Comment: I think you overlooked that a substantial chunk of work is done between 2' and 3. Admittedly some work is absorbed from 2 to 2' but the net work (area of the loop) is greater for the diesel cycle.

Comment: Thanks , got it now while studying , i didn't know that 2'->3 also produce useful work (p*dv)

Comment: @MohamedRefaat Please make the question status as solved if you have got the answer. Because the questions is still in the unanswered section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As  @Brian Drummond said ,i overlooked the work done between 2' and 3